# Fetch data on interval while listening and processing other incoming requests

Tags: node.js, express, logging

I have a Express app that runs and listens for incoming requests, I want to set up a infinite loop that fetches new data from a sensor on an interval, and update the  global state/data stored of the sensor so that I can use that state in the processing of some requests.

So the express app needs to be listening and able to process new requests, while always fetching new data from the sensor and updating the global state. How would I go about achieving this, if it is even possible seeing that Node is single threaded.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to log all data that is fetched on interval into a database, and store the latest state in the application so that it can efficiently send the "cached" data to the requester.

Comment: Is the goal to store the data from the sensor over time, or are you trying to just save time when someone makes a request?

Comment: To store the sensor data over time, and also save as much time as I can when someone makes the request, so both, but the priority is obviously on storing the data over time.

Comment: Might want to look at node-cron for scheduling tasks. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron